# Show loading message in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I want to show a loading message in my AppDelegate while check some things, and when I finish this task and obtain result using delegate dismiss this message.

How can I do this?  I implement this solution but I can't dismiss the alert.

Here I launch alert:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    _alert_news = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message: @"telo" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [_alert_news show];

    return YES;
}
```

Here, in Appdelegate too, I receive my response:

```
#pragma mark InitializeDelegate
-(void)checkState:(NSString*)State{

    NSLog(@"InitializeResult: %@",State);
    [_alert_news dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

}
```

thanks

FIXED!!
Finally I fixed this issue this way:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    _alert=   [UIAlertController
               alertControllerWithTitle:@""
               message:@"Loading GradiantFace ..."
               preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:_alert animated:YES completion:nil];


    return YES;
}

#pragma mark InitializeDelegate
-(void)checkState:(NSString*)State{

    NSLog(@"InitializeResult: %@",State);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    });


}
```

Comment: You have no Button there. And take a look at the UIAlertController, i can't link it atm, i'm mobile

Comment: better you use a progress view while other processing done

Comment: Change line 1 to  _alert_news = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message: @"telo" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

Comment: This works for me, are you sure your checkState function is being called? And check that _alert_news isn't nil.

Answer (score 3):

You should not do this. Instead create your first view controller as blank controller where you should a loader(or your message) while you load things and then replace it with your home view controller.